# Looping with steps of 0.1, but index error when trying to store results into matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a loop that uses steps of 0.1 rather than 1. However, now I don't know how to store the results into a matrix. When I loop using steps of 1, I can use these steps as the index for the results matrix, but this doesn't work when using steps of 0.1.

```
`for v in np.arange(0,5,0.1):
    for w in np.arange(0,5,0.1):
        C1 = v 
        C2 = w
        ...
        if x < 0:
            res[v,w]=1
        else:
            res[v,w]=0`
```

"res[v,w]=0 IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices"

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to the question.

Comment: res[v,w]=0

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: Why don't you use steps of 1, and divide by 10 when formatting the results.

Comment: @Barmar, I wouldn't do that. It is quite prone to errors, especially if you plan on changing the step size often. Also this is not possible while using an irrational number as a step size. It is much easier and more robust to use the built-in `enumerate` function, as this one provides you with an index for each value in the loop.

Comment: `arrays` are indexed with integers, e.g. `res[1,2]`, not with floats like `res[0.1, 0.2]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `enumerate` function to get both an index and the value. For example, you can use:

```py
for i, v in enumerate(np.arange(0,5,0.1)):
    for j, w in enumerate(np.arange(0,5,0.1)):
        # Inner loop body
```

Now, `i` and `j` can be used for indexing. For example, you can now use `res[i,j] = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers are not valid indices. You need to index only with integers.

Try this:

```
temp1 = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
temp2 = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
res = np.zeros((temp1.shape[0], temp2.shape[0]))
for i, v in enumerate(temp1):
    for j, w in enumerate(temp2):
        ...
        if x < 0:
           res[i, j] = 1
```

Comment: But how can I store the results into a matrix? The loop itself works fine with np.arange and a value of 0.1.